# How to see the input and output in storm

Tags: apache-storm

I have installed Apache Storm and also executed the example [word count topology](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter). But there was no input or output shown. How can I see it?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? http://storm-project.net/documentation.html

Comment: No we haven't study yet we will study

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Basic Understanding**

- The [manual](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Home.html) is a must-read, especially the *[Concepts](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Concepts.html)* section will help you to get a basic understanding.
- You should not only install the example topology for word count, you should also read the appendant [tutorial](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html).

**Input / Output**

- Your last bolt should transport the output to the destination. That might be a database, service, ...
- You may use logging as in any other Java application.
- If you're using the [Trident API](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Documentation#trident), there is a [Debug](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc-0.8.1/storm/trident/operation/builtin/Debug.html) filter, which you can integrate into your topology.